# How to integrate Facebook's  OAuth 2.0 in CakePHP1.3?

Tags: facebook, cakephp, cakephp-1.3, oauth-2.0

How can I use Facebook's latest OAuth 2.0 API in CakePHP?

Answer (score 0):

Does this help: [CakePHP Facebook Plugin](http://www.webtechnick.com/blogs/view/229/CakePHP_Facebook_Plugin_Auth_Facebook_and_more)